# OpenGL glfw black window

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew

I have a small problem with glfw.

My code is really simple, I juste want to create an empty window.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {


// initialise the windows
GLFWwindow *window;

if (!glfwInit()) {

    return -1;
}

// create  a windows

window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}


// make the window's current context
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
// loop until the window close

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // swap back and front buffers

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);


    // poll the events

    glfwPollEvents();
}

std::cout << "finished ";
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

}

This code compile but when I run it, I only have  a white window. The title of the window is correct but everything inside is white...
I try to use glClearColor like that

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 0);
```

but my window still white....
I use visual studio 2015.

How to get a black window ?

**Edit :**

**I forgot to add this:
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);**

Comment: Replace `glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` with `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` maybe?

Comment: You can put this in answer and close the thematic. @Skarwim

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors I'm posting the edit as a formal answer.

The thing missing here is to set the newly created window as the current OpenGL context by calling `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);`

Interestingly the comments in the code say you are doing this

> `// make the window's current context`

But then you do not call the method above but instead set the background colour immediately after. If you add the above method call after this comment and before you set the background colour then when I run your code it works fine.